# Cannot get data.Location while uploading to AWS s3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I successfully upload my files to the aws s3 bucket, but cannot get its location back , to store it back to my DB.

Here is my function:

```
const uploadFile = (filename, key) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
        fs.readFile(filename,  (err, data) => {
            if(err){

                reject(err);
            };
            const params = {
                Bucket: "BUCKET_NAME",
                Key: `student_${key}`, // File name you want to save as in S3
                Body: data,
                ACL: 'public-read'
            };
              s3.upload(params, function(err, data){
                if(err){
                    throw err;
                }
                resolve(data.Location);
                
            }); 
              
        });
    
    })

};
```

My router :

```
uploadFile.uploadFile(request.file.path, request.file.originalname).then((addr) => {
            student_photo = addr;
        })
```

Eventually I get empty string (when I `console.log` this).

Answer (score 0):

The decision I found was to create a `Promise` to a function `uploadFile`, which in terms make it "thenable". So in `.then()` part I make query request to store info in my SQL.